# Bad Create PROCEDURE in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

I'm trying to execute query in mysql. So, when i run, i receive:

```
Error Code: 1304. PROCEDURE ander already exists
```

I tried to define variable "a" with @, but is the same result - Error Code: 1304.
Actually when I execute SELECT statement is correct. So, where could be my mistake?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ander() 

BEGIN


DECLARE a int ;
SET a=1;


  WHILE a < 20
    DO

    SELECT 
    (SUM(price) + SUM(delivery_price)) as total_sum,
    COUNT(`id`) AS total_cnt,
    market_id,
    `date`,
    COUNT(`user_id`) AS total_users
    FROM orders 
    WHERE 
    (`date`>='2014-08-01 00:00:00' - INTERVAL a DAY) AND ( `date`<='2014-08-01   23:59:59' - INTERVAL a DAY)

    GROUP BY market_id;


    SET a=a+1;


    END WHILE;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `CREATE OR REPLACE`

Comment: There error is very clear: You're trying to create a sproc that already exists. This has NOTHING to do with your sproc's innards, and everything to do with its name.

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the start:

```
DROP PROCEDURE ander;
```

so you should have:

```
DROP PROCEDURE ander;

CREATE PROCEDURE ander() 

BEGIN


DECLARE a int ;
SET a=1;


  WHILE a < 20
    DO

    SELECT 
    (SUM(price) + SUM(delivery_price)) as total_sum,
    COUNT(`id`) AS total_cnt,
    market_id,
    `date`,
    COUNT(`user_id`) AS total_users
    FROM orders 
    WHERE 
    (`date`>='2014-08-01 00:00:00' - INTERVAL a DAY) AND ( `date`<='2014-08-01   23:59:59' - INTERVAL a DAY)

    GROUP BY market_id;


    SET a=a+1;


    END WHILE;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

each mysql PROCEDURE is stored in database (basically it's a database object)

you need to drop first using syntax

```
DROP PROCEDURE ander
```

Docs:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-procedure.html